# What is a data structure that has O(1) for append, prepend, and retrieve element at any location?

Tags: java, data-structures, vector, linked-list, deque

I'm looking for Java solution but any general answer is also OK.

Vector/ArrayList is O(1) for append and retrieve, but O(n) for prepend.

LinkedList (in Java implemented as doubly-linked-list) is O(1) for append and prepend, but O(n) for retrieval.

Deque (ArrayDeque) is O(1) for everything above but cannot retrieve element at arbitrary index.

In my mind a data structure that satisfy the requirement above has 2 growable list inside (one for prepend and one for append) and also stores an offset to determine where to get the element during retrieval.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to retrieve the value or a key or its position in the queue?

Comment: @Schwern: retrieve the value by index.

Comment: @ephemient - My opinion is that mixing amortized with big-O is dangerous. They often have vastly different properties in practice, and the differences should be well understood when using any algorithm.

Comment: There are some useful answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350063/java-equivalent-of-stddeque

Comment: @Hexagon: I've never seen this matter in practice. Constant factors are typically lower for dynamic array implementations than linked list implementations, and contiguous array access for large n is faster than pointer-chasing with linked lists. Space cost per element is lower with a vector implementation too. I've never seen a performance problem arise because of the occasional spike in add() time.  I've seen performance problems arise due to memory fragmentation when vectors get too large and don't shrink, but that's another issue altogether. For large n, the add() spikes don't matter much.

Comment: @tgamblin - As usual, it all depends on context. If you wish to use such a double-ended queue for storing one million elements, and update it from an interrupt context - you really DO want to make sure O(1) is O(1).
(ignoring the fact you usually don't get to allocate memory from within interrupts, that is).
All I'm advocating for is awareness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for a double-ended queue.  This is implemented the way you want in the C++ STL, which is you can index into it, but not in Java, as you noted.  You could conceivably roll your own from standard components by using two arrays and storing where "zero" is.  This could be wasteful of memory if you end up moving a long way from zero, but if you get too far you can rebase and allow the deque to crawl into a new array.

A more elegant solution that doesn't really require so much fanciness in managing two arrays is to impose a circular array onto a pre-allocated array.  This would require implementing push_front, push_back, and the resizing of the array behind it, but the conditions for resizing and such would be much cleaner.

Comment: It should be noted that adding to a deque is only amortized O(1) time... any individual add operation can be O(n) if a resize is necessary.

Comment: In the name of clarity for novice readers, "double-ended queue" == "deque". Good answer — I included some of the details for a circular buffer implementation in my answer, too.

Answer (score 5):

A **deque** (double-ended queue) may be implemented to provide all these operations in O(1) time, although not all implementations do. I've never used Java's ArrayDeque, so I thought you were joking about it not supporting random access, but you're absolutely right — as a "pure" deque, it only allows for easy access at the ends. I can see why, but that sure is annoying...

To me, the ideal way to implement an exceedingly fast deque is to use a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), especially since you are only interested in adding removing at the front and back. I'm not immediately aware of one in Java, but I've written one in Objective-C as part of an open-source framework. You're welcome to use the code, either as-is or as a pattern for implementing your own.

Here is a [WebSVN portal to the code](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/websvn/listing.php?repname=BYU+CocoaHeads&path=/CHDataStructures/source/) and the [related documentation](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/interface_c_h_circular_buffer_deque.html). The real meat is in the **CHAbstractCircularBufferCollection.m** file — look for the `appendObject:` and `prependObject:` methods. There is even a custom enumerator ("iterator" in Java) defined as well. The essential circular buffer logic is fairly trivial, and is captured in these 3 centralized `#define` macros:

```
#define transformIndex(index) ((headIndex + index) % arrayCapacity)
#define incrementIndex(index) (index = (index + 1) % arrayCapacity)
#define decrementIndex(index) (index = ((index) ? index : arrayCapacity) - 1)
```

As you can see in the `objectAtIndex:` method, all you do to access the Nth element in a deque is `array[transformIndex(N)]`. Note that I make `tailIndex` always point to one slot beyond the last stored element, so if `headIndex == tailIndex`, the array is full, or empty if the size is 0.

Hope that helps. My apologies for posting non-Java code, but the question author *did* say general answers were acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

If you treat append to a Vector/ArrayList as O(1) - which it really isn't, but might be close enough in practice -
(EDIT - to clarify - append may be *amortized constant time*, that is - on average, the addition would be O(1), but might be quite a bit worse on spikes. Depending on context and the exact constants involved, this behavior can be deadly).

(This isn't Java, but some made-up language...).

One vector that will be called "Forward".
A second vector that will be called "Backwards".

When asked to append -
`Forward.Append()`.

When asked to prepend -
`Backwards.Append()`.

When asked to query -

```
if ( Index < Backwards.Size() )
{
    return Backwards[ Backwards.Size() - Index - 1 ]
}
else
{
    return Forward[ Index - Backwards.Size() ]
}
```

(and also check for the index being out of bounds).

Comment: It really *is* O(1) -- amortized.  See the proof here: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bureshop/my_lec8.ps

Comment: Come on! The definition of O(1) is *worst case*. There are other notations for amortized constant time.
I can clarify this in my answer - but Vector append is really NOT O(1). If it would be, we wouldn't be needing linked lists...

Comment: Added a clarification in the answer for O(1) vs. amortized constant time.

Comment: I agree with @tgamblin, appending to a vector is definitely O(1) amortized. Further, the primary strength of linked lists is NOT constant-time append/prepend, it is inserting and deleting nodes at a random location inside the structure, something which arrays are especially poor at. I can't see how adding elements to linked list is any faster in aggregate — you have a ton of small allocations instead of progressively fewer large reallocations (assuming doubling on resize). The result is usually fragmented memory and lots of page faults, whereas arrays have much better locality of reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea might work. If those are the only operations you need to support, then two Vectors are all you need (call them Head and Tail). To prepend, you append to head, and to append, you append to tail. To access an element, if the index is less than head.Length, then return head[head.Length-1-index], otherwise return tail[index-head.Length]. All of these operations are clearly O(1).

Comment: It still works if you remove from the head or tail, just not so well if you remove from the middle somewhere. The author didn't state that was a requirement, so I'd say this suggestion is pretty decent. However, people like to claim O(1) but forget that their two arrays may have to resize just like a single one, and if you treat a single array as a circular buffer, you may resize less often. Even so, no one approach seems clearly better than another.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a data structure that supports O(1) append, prepend, first, last and size. We can easily add other methods from `AbstractList<A>` such as `delete` and `update`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FastAppendArrayList<A> {
    private ArrayList<A> appends = new ArrayList<A>();
    private ArrayList<A> prepends = new ArrayList<A>();

    public void append(A element) {
        appends.add(element);
    }

    public void prepend(A element) {
        prepends.add(element);
    }

    public A get(int index) {
        int i = prepends.size() - index;
        return i >= 0 ? prepends.get(i) : appends.get(index + prepends.size());
    }

    public int size() {
        return prepends.size() + appends.size();
    }

    public A first() {
        return prepends.isEmpty() ? appends.get(0) : prepends.get(prepends.size());
    }

    public A last() {
        return appends.isEmpty() ? prepends.get(0) : appends.get(prepends.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a double-ended queue (`deque`) like the STL has, since Java's `ArrayDeque` lacks `get()` for some reason.  There were some good suggestions and links to implementations here:

- [Java equivalent of std::deque?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350063/java-equivalent-of-stddeque)