# How does pop perform in O(1) in Java Queue Implementation?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I have read in [here](http://learn.hackerearth.com/forum/440/queue-with-push_rear-pop_front-and-get_min-in-constant-time/) that Java's Queue pop in O(1).

> We know that push and pop are constant time operations [O(1) to be precise (Do you know why?)].

What I don't Understand is - how?
If it's a linked list then it can't be O(1) because it has to save the last item.
If it's a doubly linked list then it can. But is it a *doubly linked list*?

Comment: I would guess this is the case because references to the first and last element are stored internally.

Comment: It would be quite cruel if they had implemented `LinkedList` as singly linked. "Hey, let's make sure nobody ever uses this!".

Comment: They use double-linked list for internal implementation. You can google more for this data structure :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984925/what-is-a-data-structure-that-has-o1-for-append-prepend-and-retrieve-element

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from Java 7 API:

> public class LinkedList extends AbstractSequentialList
>   implements List, Deque, Cloneable, Serializable
>
> **Doubly-linked list implementation** of the List and Deque interfaces.
>   Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements
>   (including null).

So yes, it's doubly-linked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take a look at the implementation of the `LinkedList`:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList (the `Deque<E>` interface extends the `Queue<E>` interface).