# Java container like c++ map

Tags: java, c++, dictionary, iterator

Are there any containers in Java which allows us to use iterator by key and which can go both to the next element and to the previous one (like maps in c++)?

p.s. sorry for my English

Comment: Does C++'s `map` guarantee any iteration ordering? This will have an influence here

Comment: @fge: Yes. `std::map` iterates in an order as if sorted by the key, based on a given ordering criterion (the default of which is a 'less than' comparison).

Comment: OK, then @nosid's answer fits the bill

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java equivalent of C++ std::map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258449/java-equivalent-of-c-stdmap)

Comment: @fge: Though there is also `std::unordered_map` which is hash based and has no guaranteed iteration order. (and the OP said "maps" not `std::map`, so he may also be including `std::unordered_map` in that)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley uhm, OK, so what is what? `map` or `unordered_map`?

Comment: @fge: `std::map` is sorted, `std::unordered_map` is hashed. But I don't know what the OP means by "map". I don't know if he is using it to specifically refer to `std::map`, or if he is using it as a generalized term for a dictionary data structure, in which case it could be `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, or even `std::multimap` or `std::unordered_multimap`.

Answer (score 9):

A [NavigableMap](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) comes closest to [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). The most commonly used implementation is [TreeMap](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

The *NavigableMap* contains a lot of methods to iterate in sorted order over the entries. The first loop iterates over all elements, whereas the second loop is restricted to a sub-range.

```
NavigableMap<String, Integer> map = ...;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    // ...
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry
   : map.subMap("bar", "foo").entrySet()) {
    // ...
}
```

It is also possible to iterate from the beginning to a certain entry, or from a certain entry to the end. Take a look at the following methods:

- [subMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20K%29)
- [headMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#headMap%28K%29)
- [tailMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#tailMap%28K%29)

In C++, *iterators* are also used for a lot of other use cases. The Java *iterators* are very different, and can not be used in combination with mutating operations. In many cases, you have to use lookups by instead of iterations. For example, the following methods return the previous and next entry (in sorted order), if the key of the current entry is used:

- [lowerEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#lowerEntry%28K%29)
- [higherEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#higherEntry%28K%29)

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look [at the official documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

I think you can use an iterator to traverse on the map's keyset to achieve what you want. Sample code here:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
        {
            put(1, "One");
            put(2, "Two");
            put(3, "Three");
            put(4, "Four");
            put(5, "Five");
        }
    };


    Iterator<Integer> iter = map.keySet().iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The LinkedList class has a listIterator method which helps you to traverse in both directions

Comment: Not only `LinkedList`, but _any_ `List` implementation... Problem is, `Map`s are not `List`s

Comment: Yes, just took it as an example.