# What is the Java equivalent of C++ deque?

Tags: java, c++, queue, deque

in C++ all I had to do was

```
#include <queue> -> including
queue<int> a; -> defining
a.push(1); ->using
```

but in java I found very difficult to use simple deque
what should I do...?
more specifically,
How should I code to simply do the same steps 
as I did in C++; including, defining, using.

even more specifically,
I want to make a deque so that I can
add any integer in the deque at front or back.
and print whole numbers in that deque by the size of the deque

Comment: A more suitable title would have been "What is the Java equivalent of C++ deque"

Comment: What do you mean by "print whole numbers in that deque by the size of the deque"?

Comment: If you use an IDE, it will help you find classes to import and how to construct the code. Free IDEs include; IntelliJ CE, Netbeans or Eclipse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java has both [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and [Deque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) types, and a [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), among others, can act as either one:

```
import java.util.*;
Deque<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
q.push(1);
```

Comment: how can i print the whole numbers in queue like if I add 1,2,3,4 in the queue it will print like 1 2 3 4

Comment: This sounds like homework. Have you even tried to do it yet? Show some code and point out where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 10):

The current answers suggest that Java's [java.util.LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is the Java translation of C++'s [std::deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/). While `LinkedList` does have an interface that is roughly equivalent to that of `std::deque`, it does not provide the complexity guarantees that `std::deque` does. In particular, `std::deque` guarantees `O(1)` lookup by index (random access), while `LinkedList` has `O(n)` lookup. In this sense (the sense in which an experienced C++ user views `std::deque`), Java's `LinkedList` is nothing at all like `std::deque` (though it is very much like `std::list`). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350063/java-equivalent-of-stddeque?rq=1) provides a better answer to the question "What is is the Java equivalent of C++ deque". To sum up, there is no equivalent in the standard Java library.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [java.util.LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

```
LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
linkedList.add(5);
linkedList.addFirst(2); // add to front, equivalent to push()
linkedList.addLast(3); // add to end, equivalent to add()
```